# Quickly duplicate the same row with 1 random column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, duplication

I need assistance duplicating a single row in phpmyadmin 1000 times with the same data except for 1 column for codes. The code has to be random.

Here's a sample:
[image]

Is there an easier way to do this than manually copying a row and updating?

Thank you!

Comment: Also, I am a complete beginner trying to work on a personal project. I just wanted to seek for the experts' advise to a problem - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Is there an easier way to do this than manually copying a row and updating?*" - Yes, you would want to write SQL code to do this, instead of using the UI of phpmyadmin. Please see the following.

You'd want to use a [CROSS JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_cross.asp) between your table and a dummy table with enough rows, such as the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html) table, and then use `LIMIT` to get exactly 1,000 rows back. You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to nondeterministically generate a sequential numerical value for your `code` column. (I'm assuming it's a number since you haven't provided the table schema.)

Here's is a general example of how to do that:

```
SELECT
    YourTable.TheFirstColumn,
    YourTable.TheSecondColumn,
    YourTable.TheThirdColumn,
    YourTable.AnyOtherColumns,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS code
FROM YourTable
CROSS JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Thank you for the references! I'll take time to read through them and learn. appreciate it!